# Как получить текст ошибки, которую сгенерировала функция scandir в PHP

Tags: php

Возможно ли получить текст ошибки (если она была сгенерирована) функции scandir, то есть записать её в переменную?

Comment: `Возвращает массив (array) имён файлов в случае успешного выполнения или false в случае возникновения ошибки. Если directory не является каталогом, возвращается false и генерируется сообщение об ошибке уровня E_WARNING.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207932/how-to-check-if-scandir-returns-any-error-or-warning

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что автор хочет что-то такое: [Can I try/catch a warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо! Именно то, что нужно.